# have exception error when using Visa.Interop.ResourceManager in C#

Tags: c#, resourcemanager, visa

I'm using C# to control instrument(ex. function generator) but when using ResourceManager constructor some exception error occurs...
This is the exception **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'(System.Private.CoreLib.dll)**

Could anyone help me with how to fix it?
I'm using Visual Studio and I've tried executing Visual Studio in administrator mode but it doesn't work either. hers's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Ivi.Visa;
using Ivi.Visa.FormattedIO;
using Ivi.Visa.Interop;
// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace upw_test1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        bool isconnected;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            isconnected = false;

        }


        void Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            connection_result.Text = "Hello, " + Input_num.Text + "!";
            if (!isconnected)
            {
                string srcAddress = "GPIB::";
                srcAddress += Input_num.Text.ToString();
                srcAddress += "::INSTR";

                try
                {
                    ResourceManager mngr = new ResourceManager();
                    
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                    connection_result.Text = srcAddress + "  connection fail  ";
                }
                // GPIB address

      

            }
        }

    }
}
```

[below is the full stack trace of exception..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZIK5.png)

Comment: remove unnecessary code :) it makes better your question.

Comment: Can you show the whole exception (including call stack), as they sometimes contain more useful information.

Comment: @Neil is the picture is what you need?

Comment: No we need the exception stack trace.  Put the text of the whole stack trace you get from that catch

Comment: @Neil i'm trying to solve creating instance of COM library but i can't find how to.. can you tell me how to solve it specifically? check the picture i attached please...

Comment: It's better to copy and paste the text error message rather than screenshots.   The error is on the 2nd line of the message! Can you read it back to me?

Comment: @Neil Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {DB8CBF1C-D6D3-11D4-AA51-00A024EE30BD} using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the
following error::80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).Please make sure your COM object is in
the allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromAPP

Comment: sorry for late reply

Comment: 'Class not registered' ! You haven't installed the COM component.